# Filtering a DataGridView with a BindingList

Tags: .net, datagridview, filtering, bindingsource

I've created a WinForms application with a DataGridView and I'd like to filter it. It's setup as follows:

A catalogue entry:

```
public class CatalogueEntry
{
    private string _code;
    private string _desc;

    public CatalogueEntry(string code, string desc)
    {
        _code = code;
        _desc = desc;
    }

    public string Code => _code;
    public string Description => _desc;
}
```

The catalogue list (using BindingList):

```
public class Catalogue : BindingList<CatalogueEntry>
{

}
```

Initialisation:

```
_catalogue = new Catalogue();

_catalogue.Add(new CatalogueEntry("BAGG", "It scares us all"));
_catalogue.Add(new CatalogueEntry("BIGG", "It embiggens us all"));
_catalogue.Add(new CatalogueEntry("BOGG", "It demeans us all"));
_catalogue.Add(new CatalogueEntry("BUGG", "It frightens us all"));

_source = new BindingSource();
_source.DataSource = _catalogue;

dataGridView.DataSource = _source;
```

I get a nice grid of the above data.

If I try to set the filter on the BindingSource as follows:

```
var filter = "Description like 'scares'";
_source.Filter = filter;
```

Nothing happens, i.e. the filter doesn't appear to work. What can I do to get the filter working?

I'm guessing the underlying data source isn't a database so won't understand "Description like 'scares'".

EDIT: If I change my filter as follows:

```
var text = "scares";
var list = _catalogue.Where(entry => entry.Description.Contains(text));
_source.DataSource = list;
```

then it filters as required; however this is changing the list. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `_source.SupportsFiltering`, you'll find it's `False`. According to MSDN Documentation on [`BindingSource.Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(VS.90).aspx):

> Only underlying lists that implement the [IBindingListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview(v=vs.90).aspx) interface support filtering.

Which `BindingList` does not:

```
public class BindingList<T> : Collection<T>, IBindingList, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICancelAddNew, IRaiseItemChangedEvents
```

While what you have will suffice for simple purposes, if you need real filtering without changing the `DataSource`, you can:

1. Find a generic implementation of `IBindingListView` library created by other users.
2. Roll your own implementation (lot of work but more customizable).
3. Restructure - think `DataTable` instead.

Comment: I went for option 2 - then simply implemented functions if the default bare bones version hit one of the "not implemented" exceptions. Filtering works fine. Also, I only needed to implement IBindingListView as that includes IBindingList

Comment: Awesome!  Sorry about that error in my post.  I just realized I said implement `IBindingList` in my options instead of `IBindingListView`, but I'm glad you correctly interpreted what I meant.  - Edited to correct.